# Flask-SQLAlchemy using global DB instance

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is what I did:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

    dbhost = 'localhost'
    dbuser = 'user'
    dbpass = 'password'
    dbname = 'db'
    DBUri = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8'%(dbuser,dbpass,dbhost,dbname)

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = (DBUri)
    app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'


    # an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
    # resources
    engine = create_engine(DBUri)

    # create a configured "Session" class
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    # create a Session
    DBsession = Session()
```

and

```
@sched.cron_schedule(second='*/5')
def some_decorated_task():
    date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    for item in DBsession.query(user_groups_n_hosts).filter(user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now)): 
        print item.id, item.server_users.native_linux_user
```

there is a table **user_groups_n_hosts** The above code is a function that runs every 30 seconds.

My problem is that Once I start my Flask application at that time if the **user_groups_n_hosts** has 10 records then the above code will keep printing 10 records no matter whatever number of records get inserted in the table **user_groups_n_hosts** from outside. In other words what I think is that My function has some instance of the table which is only initialized in the beginning of the initialization of the app.
I know I am doing something stupid. please someone point it out.

in place of `DBsession.query(user_groups_n_hosts).filter(user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now)):`
I tried `user_groups_n_hosts.query.filter(user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now)):`
But the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now) compares a date with a string.

Also, you should consider the session as a per-request thing, not a persistent entity across your app.

With this in mind, try changing

```
@sched.cron_schedule(second='*/5')
def some_decorated_task():
    date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    for item in DBsession.query(user_groups_n_hosts).filter(user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now)): 
        print item.id, item.server_users.native_linux_user
```

to

```
@sched.cron_schedule(second='*/5')
def some_decorated_task():
    date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    sess = Session()
    for item in sess.query(user_groups_n_hosts).filter(user_groups_n_hosts.end_time < str(date_now)): 
        print item.id, item.server_users.native_linux_user
    sess.close()
```

Comment: "Also, you should consider the session as a per-request thing, not a persistent entity across your app." -> I would recommend using SQLAlchemy's `scoped_session` here which takes care of thread safety automatically, i.e. it sets up a separate session for every thread/request, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html .

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish a fresh transaction every time.
And you can either create an entirely new session object each run, our reuse the session, but make sure that you [`commit()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit), [`rollback()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.rollback) or [`close()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.close) it after your query.

The effect is caused by some default policy of MySQL.

If you're using InnoDB as the default Storage Engine for MySQL, then it is using [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) as its isolation level. This is the default, because in most cases it makes sense to avoid [Non-repeatable Reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Non-repeatable_reads) inside transactions.
So, if you don't end your transaction you'll get the same results from the database each time.

From the the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it):

> The Session, whenever it is used to talk to the database, begins a database transaction as soon as it starts communicating. Assuming the autocommit flag is left at its recommended default of False, this transaction remains in progress until the Session is rolled back, committed, or closed. The Session will begin a new transaction if it is used again, subsequent to the previous transaction ending; from this it follows that the Session is capable of having a lifespan across many transactions, though only one at a time. We refer to these two concepts as **transaction scope** and **session scope**.

Another option, *which is not recommended*, is creating the Session with [`autocommit=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_transaction.html#autocommit-mode), which will automatically commit the transaction after each and every query statement.